# Mail host on .env laravel doesn't change Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I launched **sudo nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon** on my server with laravel 5.1, and now I have change **MAIL_HOST** in my **.env**, (before I had "mail.mysitem.com" and now I put my intern ip example : 192.168.1.212 ) but it still send mail with old hostname, how I can apply change on .env?

I tried also with:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: Take a look in `config/mail.php` if there is no hardcoded value in there.

Comment: hello, No, in my config/mail.php I have: 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', '192.168.1.212'),

Comment: If you are running the worker as a `daemon` then it won't reload the framework when it runs, meaning any changes you make won't be picked up until the queue worker is restarted. Restart the queue worker. [See the docs here for full info.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment)

Comment: hello samiles, thankyou, I have restarted with php artisan queue:restart but it doesn't work, use still old configuration

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try with:

php artisan config:clear